# 'heroku.pkg' can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: heroku, installation

When I try to install Heroku, I get this message:

“'heroku.pkg' can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software."

I'm using macOS Catalina version 10.15. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku is aware of this issue and is working on it. From their website:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install

> Currently, the macOS installer on Catalina displays an “unknown
>   author” warning. We are working to address this.

Try running this command in your terminal instead:

```
brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone having the same problem just go to "System Preferences" and under security in the General tab click on the lock below and allow the named app to Open anyways.